# Can't mount portable HDD - Cannot run commands on its partitions either

Tags: mount, disk, fsck, external-hdd

My Imation Apollo M100 portable disk is not mounting.

One day I was copying a heavy file to it, the process got stuck and I unplugged it from the computer. When I connected it back to the PC and when to see its folders problems came out.

First, it was very slow, then I wasn't able to see the drive in the file explorer because it was not mounting. Also when it is trying to mount the file explorer software, Disks application and doing `ls /media/cesc/` in a terminal window hang until the drive stops trying to mount.

Everything I've found is about running `fsck` command on the damage file system BUT I can't because it doesn't appear when I run `df -h`.

This is the ouput from `dmesg`. It cleary says that one of the partitions file system is broken and needs to be fixed:

```
[   51.965845] init: anacron main process (1325) killed by TERM signal
[   83.019268] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   83.038703] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0718, idProduct=1905
[   83.038707] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=5, SerialNumber=6
[   83.038709] usb 4-1: Product: M100 USB 3
[   83.038711] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Imation
[   83.038712] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 00000000000000000000000013
[   83.836745] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   83.836810] scsi6 : usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[   83.836871] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   83.842386] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[   87.830998] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Imation  M100 USB 3       0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[   87.831277] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[   87.831649] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[   87.832040] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[   87.832043] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[   87.832429] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[   87.832432] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   87.866595]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 sdc3
[   87.898629] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[   88.827960] FAT-fs (sdc1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[   89.016541] hfsplus: write access to a journaled filesystem is not supported, use the force option at your own risk, mounting read-only.
[   92.629715] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   92.647871] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8801fada2f00
[   92.647875] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8801fada2f48
[   92.866946] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
[   92.866950] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[   92.866952] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   92.866954] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
[   92.866955] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 01 d8 00 00 4a 00
[   92.866962] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 472
[  143.153123] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Command completion event does not match command
[  143.153156] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  148.376995] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  148.581217] usb 4-1: device not accepting address 2, error -62
[  154.385998] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Command completion event does not match command
[  154.386040] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  159.609793] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  159.814136] usb 4-1: device not accepting address 2, error -62
[  165.618842] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Command completion event does not match command
[  165.618899] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  170.842626] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  171.046926] usb 4-1: device not accepting address 2, error -62
[  176.851706] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Command completion event does not match command
[  176.851749] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  182.075515] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  182.279805] usb 4-1: device not accepting address 2, error -62
[  182.280253] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
[  182.280265] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[  182.280271] Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  182.280277] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
[  182.280280] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 01 d9 00 00 49 00
[  182.280300] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 473
[  182.280364] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  182.285970] scsi 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  182.285983] scsi 6:0:0:0: [sdc] killing request
[  182.286006] scsi 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
[  182.286012] scsi 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[  182.286018] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  182.286024] scsi 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
[  182.286028] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 01 d8 00 00 01 00
[  182.286053] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 472
[  182.286089] FAT-fs (sdc1): FAT read failed (blocknr 470)
[  182.286950] FAT-fs (sdc1): FAT read failed (blocknr 32)
[  182.287348] FAT-fs (sdc1): FAT read failed (blocknr 32)
[  182.300059] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8801fada2f00
[  182.300069] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8801fada2f48
```

In order for me to be able to run `fsck /dev/sdc1` it needs to be somehow available but it is not.

This is the output for `df -h` when is trying to mount:

```
df: ‘/media/cesc/FLAMEL’: Input/output error
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,9G  4,0K  3,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           789M  1,6M  787M   1% /run
/dev/sda7        20G   15G  3,6G  81% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            3,9G  672K  3,9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   12K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda9       166G   45G  113G  29% /home
/dev/sda2       256M   55M  202M  22% /boot/efi
/dev/sdc3        15G  7,6G  6,6G  54% /media/cesc/MAQUIAVELO
/dev/sdc2       266G   49G  217G  19% /media/cesc/PERENELL
```

`/dev/sdc1` doesn't appear.

If I try `fsck /dev/sdc1` I get:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sdc1
Possibly non-existent device?
```

Given the situation my questions are:

1. Is my disk beyond repair?
2. If not, Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `lsblk` say? What does `parted /dev/sdc` say?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any question that your drive is either dead or dying.

It doesn't appear when you run `df -h` because it's not mounted. If it doesn't appear when you run `fdisk -l` or `lsblk` or if you can't run `fsck` on the disk itself via `fsck /dev/sdc` or when it's connected to a different port and/or with a different cable then it's done. Hopefully, you have a backup of the data.